# Flex layout with text-wrap and flex-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a vertical list of several items. Every item is a two column layout made with flexbox. The left column has a fixed width. The right column contains arbitrary text and should take all the available space.

When the windows gets narrower, I still want a two column layout. Here the second column should get smaller and the text inside should wrap.

When the windows gets even narrower (second column is roughly the same size as the first column), I want the second column to move under the first.

I simply gave the first column a fixed width and put `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container. The problem is, that the flex-wrap already kicks in when the text in the right column is more than one line. It "has priority over" the text-wrap within the second column.

How can I create the layout described above?

I created a codepen with my issue to play around with: https://codepen.io/maxwell89/pen/PoWrBzJ.

```css
main {
  border: thin solid black;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article header {
  margin-right: 2em;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: red;
}

article section {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      <header>Header1</header>
      <section>iaOIsadjio jiasdj asd you asda sad iaeojrasod aosidjasdjias diojsadiojas oidjasjio dasijod asd</section>
    </article>
    <article>
      <header>Header2</header>
      <section>Something short</section>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

Try resizing the browser window and you see that the first item wraps way too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `flex-basis` of the second element to be equal to the width of the first one. Doing this, you will trigger the wrap when that width cannot fit inside the container.

```css
main {
  border: thin solid black;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article header {
  margin-right: 2em;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: red;
}

article section {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-basis: 5em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <header>Header1</header>
    <section>iaOIsadjio jiasdj asd you asda sad iaeojrasod aosidjasdjias diojsadiojas oidjasjio dasijod asd</section>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>Header2</header>
    <section>Something short</section>
  </article>
</main>
```